# Ask user to setup up email if user has not setup an email

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have to display the setup email screen in iOS if user has not already setup an email.
So when `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` returns `NO` I need to display following screen[image: Email Setup Screen]

Is this possible ? How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but you can try this:

```
NSString *recipients = @"mailto:myemail@yahoo.com?subject=subjecthere";
NSString *body = @"&body=bodyHere";

NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I added this in the else part as the it does not go back to the app when you cancel the email sending